# Function property vs method

Tags: typescript

What practical differences are there between defining an interface method:

```
interface Foo {
    bar(): void;
}
```

and defining a property with a function type:

```
interface Foo {
    bar: () => void;
}
```

?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If these are the only declarations, these are identical.

The only difference is that you can *augment* the first form in a second declaration to add new signatures:

```
// Somewhere
interface Foo {
  bar(): void;
}

// Somewhere else
interface Foo {
  bar(s: number): void;
}

// Elsewhere
let x: Foo = ...
x.bar(32); // OK
```

Comment: It is not the only difference. Please see the answers by tusharmath and Zev Spitz.

Answer (score 39):

There is another difference, in that the `readonly` modifier cannot be applied to methods. Therefore, the following assignment cannot be prevented:

```
interface Foo {
    bar(): void;
}

declare var x: Foo;
x.bar = function () { };
```

If `bar` is defined as a property, then the `readonly` modifier can be applied to it:

```
interface Foo {
    readonly bar: () => void;
}
```

preventing reassignment.

([Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20Foo1%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar()%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Adeclare%20var%20x1%3A%20Foo1%3B%0D%0Ax1.bar%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Foo2%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20readonly%20bar%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20void%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Adeclare%20var%20x2%3A%20Foo2%3B%0D%0Ax2.bar%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%7D%3B))

Comment: Very good observation and addition to the question. Actually very useful thing to know.

Answer (score 27):

The most critical difference is actually that using the property approach typescript actually checks contravariently for types. For Eg:

```
type FProp<A> = {
  fork: (a: A) => void  
}
type FMeth<A> = {
  fork(a: A): void  
}

type Cat = {
  isPurring: boolean
}

type Dog = {
  isBarking: boolean
}


const dd = { fork: (a: Cat & Dog) => void 0 }

const fa: FProp<Cat> = dd // will throw up
const fb: FMeth<Cat> = dd // will not issue any error
```

This is documented —

> The stricter checking applies to all function types, except those
>   originating in method or constructor declarations. Methods are
>   excluded specifically to ensure generic classes and interfaces (such
>   as Array) continue to mostly relate covariantly.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html

Comment: I think this answer should be better than the accepted.

Answer (score 9):

It seems that the compiler doesn't seem to care, as all of these are valid:

```
interface Foo1 {
    bar(): void;
}

class Foo1Class1 implements Foo1 {
    bar = () => { }
}

class Foo1Class2 implements Foo1 {
    bar() { }
}

interface Foo2 {
    bar: () => void;
}

class Foo2Class1 implements Foo2 {
    bar = () => { }
}

class Foo2Class2 implements Foo2 {
    bar() { }
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Foo1%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar()%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Foo1Class1%20implements%20Foo1%20%7B%0D%0A%09bar%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Foo1Class2%20implements%20Foo1%20%7B%0D%0A%09bar()%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Foo2%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20void%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Foo2Class1%20implements%20Foo2%20%7B%0D%0A%09bar%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Foo2Class2%20implements%20Foo2%20%7B%0D%0A%09bar()%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D))

The reason for that is probably to do with how that compiles into javascript:

```
var Foo1Class1 = (function () {
    function Foo1Class1() {
        this.bar = function () { };
    }
    return Foo1Class1;
}());
var Foo1Class2 = (function () {
    function Foo1Class2() {
    }
    Foo1Class2.prototype.bar = function () { };
    return Foo1Class2;
}());
```

In both cases an instance of one of those classes will have a property named `bar` which is a callable function.
The difference is only that in `Foo1Class2` the `bar` method is part of the prototype which can then be overriden by an extending class.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to create overloads for methods mean while you can't do that with properties:

```
interface JQuery {
    ok(command: "destroy"): JQuery,
    ok(command: "get_node", nodeId: string): unknown,
    //=====================
    notOk: () => unknown,
    notOk: (str: string) => unknown
}
```