# Typescript: Difference between => and : in interface function declaration

Tags: typescript

What is the difference between defining a function in an interface like:

```
interface IMyInterface1 {
    functionName(value: string): void;
}
```

and

```
interface IMyInterface2 {
    functionName: (value: string) => void;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Function property vs method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39156315/function-property-vs-method)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no real difference here, you can use which one you feel more comfortable with.
With that being said, I consider the first to imply a class method while the second is a member which is a function:

```
class MyClass1 implements IMyInterface1 {
    functionName(value: string): void {}
}

class MyClass2 implements IMyInterface2 {
    functionName = function(value: string): void {}
}
```

It is just a personal preference, the compiler will let you do the opposite as well:

```
class MyClass1 implements IMyInterface1 {
    functionName = function(value: string): void {}
}

class MyClass2 implements IMyInterface2 {
    functionName(value: string): void {}
}
```

In a similar way, these two notations are the same:

```
let obj1 = {
    functionName() {}
}

let obj2 = {
    functionName: function() {}
}
```

As they are both compiled to:

```
var obj1 = {
    functionName: function () { }
};
var obj2 = {
    functionName: function () { }
};
```

Comment: These may be effectively very similar, but they are actually different in compiler behavior, see the discussion on [Strict Function Types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/18654) in the Typescript github. The Typescript ESLint also has [rules for evaluating them differently](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/method-signature-style.md).