# Typescript type / interface to describe interface method

Tags: typescript

I have function definitions declared as type and interface:

```
// these definitions are reused elsewhere
export interface ReadBook {
  (name: string): void;
}
export type ReadLetter = (content: string) => void;
```

Interface members of these interface / type become `property`, not `method`. This seems strange compared to 'inline' function member. IDEs may also show them differently to interface clients.

```
export interface Reader {
  // property
  readBook: ReadBook;
  readLetter: ReadLetter;

  // method
  readJournal(name: string): void;
}
```

Is there a way to declare `method` interface member of reusable shape?

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39156315/function-property-vs-method and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45624452/typescript-difference-between-and-in-interface-function-declaration