# Different ways to specify methods in typescript - what is the difference

Tags: typescript

It seems like I can specify the signature of an object's method in two different ways that both work. What exactly is the difference between them?

A

```
interface MyInterface {
        validatedModel: (model: myValidatedModel) => myValidatedModel;
    }
```

B

```
 interface MyInterface {
        validatedModel(model: myValidatedModel) : myValidatedModel;
    }
```

Comment: In the first example, you are defining a property whose type is a function. In the second example, you are defining a method. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39156315/function-property-vs-method).

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be any difference. 
If you implement both interfaces in the same class a method with the same signature will satisfy both.

```js
interface MyInterface {
    validatedModel: (model: string) => string;
}

interface MyOtherInterface {
    validatedModel(model: string): string;
}

class A implements MyInterface, MyOtherInterface {
    validatedModel(model: string) {
        return model;
    }
}
```

See it in the playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20MyInterface%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20validatedModel%3A%20(model%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20MyOtherInterface%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20validatedModel(model%3A%20string)%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20A%20implements%20MyInterface%2C%20MyOtherInterface%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20validatedModel(model%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20model%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D).

Comment: I just wondered about this apparent nebulous syntactic requirements

Comment: I tried to find a reason for the `=>` being syntactically different in this case but I didn't find one. Maybe it's historical (it used to be that way in the past). I didn't find anything in the documentation though.