# Defining a getter using prototype causes "unbound-method" ts-lint error

Tags: javascript, typescript, prototype, getter, tslint

I have written simple package for my pet project where I am extending prototype chain to add plugin functionality. Everything works fine by declaring methods, but I have an error.

```
declare module "../module" {
    interface Module {
      method(): void;
      property(): number;
}

export const plugin: Plugin = (BaseClass): void => {
    BaseClass.prototype.method= function(): void {
        // this works fine
    };

    Object.defineProperty(BaseClass.prototype, "property", {
        get: function property() {
            return 5;
        }
    };
});
```

After that, using my package with this plugin I have an error when I try to use getter.
Code works fine, but ts-lint don't like me and yells constantly.

```
// Error: @typescript-eslint/unbound-method
const variable = instance.property;
```

Am I doing something wrong declaring a getter?

Answer (score 1):

I think I got it, [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get#get_vs._defineproperty) explains the problem. `Object.defineProperty()` bound the getter to instance, not on prototype.

Edit:

I was wrong, `Object.defineProperty()` is fine. The problem was in incorrect type declaration:

```
declare module "../module" {
    interface Module {
      method(): void;
      property(): () => number;
}
```

Now it works fine.

**Final edit:**

```
declare module "../module" {
    interface Module {
      method(): void;
      readonly property: number;
}
```

Now it defines a getter properly, all errors gone away. The problem was in declaring getter properly.

Comment: You are right, I am wrong. After some digging into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39156315/function-property-vs-method), I think the problem is in invalid type.