# Generic static constructor in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I tend to use a static constructor `Foo.of()`/`Foo.from()` methods instead of the classic class constructor that has to be called with `new`. I find this terser, easier to read, and like that it can be used pointfree. However, as a result, I end up writing a lot of boilerplate like this:

```
class Foo<T> {
  constructor(private value: T) {}
  static of<T>(value: T) {
    return new Foo(value);
  }
}

class Bar<T, U> {
  constructor(private value1: T, private value2: U) {}
  static of<T, U>(value1: T, value2: U) {
    return new Bar(value1, value2);
  }
}
```

Is there any way to e.g. use a decorator (+ an interface, potentially) so that could avoid having to declare the `of` method each time, but could instead do something like:

```
type Constructor = new (...args: any) => any;
interface Constructable<T extends Constructor> {
  static of(...args: Parameters<T>): T;
}

function constructable<T>(constructor: Constructor) { ... }

// ....

@constructable
class Foo<T> {
    constructor(private value: T) {}
}
interface Foo<T> extends Constructable<Foo<T>> {}

@constructable
class Bar<T, U> {
    constructor(private value1: T, value2: U) {}
}
interface Bar<T, U> extends Constructable<Bar<T, U>> {}

const foo = Foo.of(10)
const bar = Bar.of(10, 20)
```

Comment: Decorators won't mutate the type of the constructor, and neither will similar approaches like assertion functions.  To do this you'd need more boilerplate per class, and `private` properties probably won't work. If you care about pointfree style then maybe you just want a wrapper that turns a constructor into a function, as shown [in this playground link](//tsplay.dev/Wy2QAw).  So instead of `Foo.of(10)` you can write `of(Foo)(10)`, and `of(Foo)` can be passed around as your pointfree thingy. If that fully addresses the question I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks, so you're saying that decorators are just applied to the constructor but cannot mutate it? Idk, I would just like some terse way of being able to instantiate classes and pass the constructor around, without having to use `new`. Something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/44061744/11217758 would work too, i.e. `Foo(10)` instead of `new Foo(10)`, but I wasn't able to type that answer properly.

Comment: Decorators don't mutate the *type* of a class (including the static side) and most of the other approaches I can come up with will simply lose the generics on `Foo` and `Bar`; the only way to preserve those is with [the support for higher order function inference](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-functions) which really constrains the solution to something like my standalone `of()`. Is `of(Foo)` not terse enough?  I'm trying to understand whether I should write up an answer or if you're not satisfied with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a helper function rather than a decorator.

Decorators are intentionally designed "to metaprogram and add functionality to a value, *without* fundamentally changing its external behavior"([tc39/proposal-decorators: Decorators for ES6 classes](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators), *emphasis* added). Adding a new static method to a constructor type would fundamentally change its external behavior as it changes its public interface.

If you'll be exporting and importing the helper function then you might find it easier to write the small amount of boilerplate but here's an example of what you can do:

```
function of<T, P extends unknown[]>(constructor: new (...args: P) => T) {
  return (...args: P) => new constructor(...args);
}

class Foo<T> {
  constructor(private value: T) {}
  static of = of(this);
}

class Bar<T, U> {
  constructor(private value1: T, private value2: U) {}
  static of = of(this);
}

const foo = Foo.of(10);
//    ^? const foo: Foo<number>
const bar = Bar.of(10, 20);
//    ^? const bar: Bar<number, number>
```

Note that TypeScript will no longer treat `Foo.of()` and `Bar.of()` as *methods* but as *properties* and there are some tradeoffs with such (see [Function property vs method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39156315/3255152)).